# Django data handling?

Tags: python, django, yui

I have successfully posted to the server side and can see my data delivered in the request payload. The payload is structured as

```
[{C1:R0, C2:R0, C3:R0},{C1:R1, C2:R1, C3:R1},...,{C1:Rn, C2:Rn, C3:Rn}]
```

I want to read this data in my **views.py** file and write it to the table that has columns that correspond to the C1, C2, and C3. Basically the columns represent readings and I am trying to log these reading in a table. How do I extract the raw string and insert these values into the table?

I am using Python/Django.

Comment: Is the data being sent as-is ? You should have some kind of a key=value relationship right? Use a form submit. It would make things so much more simpler

Comment: the key values are created automatically by Django in the **models.py** but I don't really care about them. I never will look up data from this table by primary key id. One column in my data is a session_id which will be used to call these. I just want the data to go in the table and be quick and take as little memory as possible. Do you still suggest a form submit?

Comment: I was not talking about keys for the model. I was talking about the key for the form's submit. YES, i would recommend it highly.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are talking about. The data is not user input. The data is randomly generated from a few user inputs and put into an HTML table. The data is then read from a table and stored into the JSON object which is then posted to the server. I just want to read that JSON object and for the array insert each {} group as a row. I don't see how a form makes this easier?